# Problems changing SVG image from one to another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to use https://applause-button.com/ this button but turn the hands into a heart instead, but I'm having some trouble with it. I know I need to change the SVG image somehow, but I don't really understand how. Just changing the numbers in "path d" didn't change anything.

I'm trying to change it to this one:
https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/503037/heart

I tried to add the JS here but it exceeded the character limit so here's a codepen:
https://codepen.io/thepasteldyke/pen/LYqYKRg

I tried to put this code from the downloaded SVG file into the JS file, but I must've done it in the wrong place or something, cus that didn't work for me either. I tried replacing all the "path d" in the file with no success.

This is the code for the image I want instead of the hands:

```
<svg width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M12.39 20.87a.696.696 0 0 1-.78 0C9.764 19.637 2 14.15 2 8.973c0-6.68 7.85-7.75 10-3.25 2.15-4.5 10-3.43 10 3.25 0 5.178-7.764 10.664-9.61 11.895z" fill="#000000"/></svg>
```

What section of the JS do I replace? I already tried changing the CSS but it seems like the symbol is somewhere in the JS section, not the CSS or the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an open-source project you can look at the source code...
Look at the unminified javascript code here: https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/applause-button/blob/master/src/applause-button.js

At line 78, we see the start of the svg.
We see that the SVG is in two parts: two g tags with each class "flat" or "outline".
We must therefore adjust the svg to correspond to the one we wish to replace:

```
<svg width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g class="flat"><path d="M12.39 20.87a.696.696 0 0 1-.78 0C9.764 19.637 2 14.15 2 8.973c0-6.68 7.85-7.75 10-3.25 2.15-4.5 10-3.43 10 3.25 0 5.178-7.764 10.664-9.61 11.895z"/></g><g class="outline" fill="none"><path d="M12.39 20.87a.696.696 0 0 1-.78 0C9.764 19.637 2 14.15 2 8.973c0-6.68 7.85-7.75 10-3.25 2.15-4.5 10-3.43 10 3.25 0 5.178-7.764 10.664-9.61 11.895z"/></g></svg>
```

After a test we see that the SVG outline is not displayed, this is because the library also uses fill for the color of the stroke. You need to modify your css by deleting the line "stroke:none;" in your "applause-button svg" selector

Here is the result :
https://codepen.io/SioGabx/pen/RwvwXxp

Comment: I'm trying not to just copy/paste your code so I actually try and understand what you mean, but from what I can tell I think you used the minified version (I didn't even know there were different versions. so that's where the mod on w3 discord got the div classes etc... when i asked I just got condescension back...) but the one I have is all compressed into one line which makes it really hard to read. Where did you find the minified version that isn't all in one huge block of illegible text?

Comment: Everyone starts at some point and it's a good thing to try to understand.
If you want to know more about why your code you downloaded is in one block, you can read this : https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/performance/why-minify-javascript-code/

In your case, the page https://applause-button.com/ had a link to the github where we can find the original files.
The version of the code that I have on the codepen is indeed the minified version but it is indented (automatically).
For your code editor, there are plugins to do that or you can search on Google for "javascript beautifier online"

Comment: If I wanted the button to change colour on hover, how would I do that? Or would you recommend asking a new question about that entirely? I'm not managing to figure it out.

Comment: @Frejr it's good, check this : https://codepen.io/SioGabx/pen/Jjxdedy
I added explanations in the pen